# Creating static and dynamic tabs on a single page

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tabs

I have a requirement, where I have to create tabs. First two tabs are static tabs, next tabs are dynamic based on the records in database table.

When I try to create, only first tabs are coming, remaining tabs are not coming.

Here is my work

```
   <p:tabView id="view1" value="#{bean.values}" var="tab" dynamic="true">
        <p:tab id="view11" title="${msgs.ckd_title}">       
                // first tab content
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab id="view12" title="${msgs.pc_qsys_title_material}">
              // second tab content
        </p:tab>
        <p:tabView id="view13"      value="#{bean.values}" var="tab">
           <p:tab id="view3" title="#{tab.label}">
                //dynamic tab content
          </p:tab>
     </p:tabView>
 </p:tabView>
```

I tried with `ui:repeat`, still no luck

Comment: do you try to create tabView inside tabView why not simplly render your tabs or block it ?!?

Comment: Could you please elaborate what do you mean by simply render or block it? @Yagami Light

Comment: if it is a visibility question (i don't want this user to see this tab) it will simplly work with rendred, if you want to generated dynamic tab (every time it's a new tab number) it's an other case (it was just a clarification questio)

Comment: they are not visibility tabs, they are always visible. First two are fixed tabs, next tabs may be 2, 4 or any number..

Comment: 'dynamic' is a broad concept. If the number is dynamic, decided on view creation and does not change during using the view (no tab-add or tab-delete), just use a `c:foreach` instead of a `ui:repeat`. The `p:tabView` at render time only accepts `p:tab` which a `c:foreach` generates.

Answer (score -1):

```
<p:tabView id="supersetTabs"value="#{pcSuperSetReportBean.plantSuperSets}" var="tab">
    <p:tab id="provisioninReportBySupplier" title="#{tab.label}">
        //dynamic tab content
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

"Dynamic" implies that bean logic is going to generate variable tab content.  So your bean will have to populate the model referred to by `value` and 
something (either an `update` parameter on a page component, or bean code) will have to tell the page to refresh the tabview `supersetTabs`.

Comment: And of you actually meant to use a tabview in a tabview but not in a tab, check if that actually works (it does not)

Comment: My answer is fine.  If you want to improve it, go ahead.

Comment: Compare your answer with the (slightly corrected) code in the original question (most likely a bad typo but which you most likely focussed on). There is no difference any more in the 'supersetTabs' part. You have not combined static and dynamic tabs in one tabview. So your answers does not add anything new to the case. Or do I miss something?